# CSS directory linking issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a directory as follows:

```
    ├──DataTables-1.10.9
    |   └── media
    |        ├── css
    |        └── js
    ├── public
    |   ├── javascripts
    |   └── stylesheets
    └── routes
        ├── index.hbs
        └── home.hbs
```

In my `index.hbs` file I have a `script` at the bottom which is something like this:

```
<script src="javascripts/bootbox.min.js"></script>
```

And this works fine. However, I try to link `DataTables`js and css from `home.hbs` and I'm having a 404 issue. In home.hbs my code is:

```
<script src="DataTables-1.10.9/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

I can't figure out why it's not working.

I also tried doing `/DataTables` and `../DataTables` and `../../DataTables`.

When I move the `jquery.dataTables.js` file into `javascripts` it works, but this is bad because it calls other `js` files in `DataTables` so I would rather use the `DataTables` directory.

Comment: Move "DataTables-1.10.9" folder inside public and everything will work.. :-) .. I meant isn't it obvious?

Comment: So you're saying it would it only work when it's put inside public? Is this always the case? From what I know, it looks bad organization-wise.

Comment: Yes. HTML is visible (and manipulatable) by the public, so allowing direct inclusion of anything before the designated public directory is too risky.

Comment: @connexo `.handlebars` file

Comment: Never heard that. What is it? Cannot find information about in your question or in your tags.

Comment: Does the console produce any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the page perspective only things on internet can be used.

```
    ├──DataTables-1.10.9
    |   └── media
    |        ├── css
    |        └── js
    ├── public
    |   ├── javascripts
    |   └── stylesheets
    └── routes
        ├── index.hbs
        └── home.hbs
```

Putting on public should works:

```
    ├── public
    |   ├── javascripts
    |   ├── stylesheets
    |   └── DataTables-1.10.9
    |        └── media
    |            ├── css
    |            └── js
    └── routes
        ├── index.hbs
        └── home.hbs
```

Perheps I would use a structure more organized, like this one:

```
    ├── public
    |   └── assets
    |     ├── stylesheets
    |     ├── javascripts
    |     └── vendor
    |         ├── DataTables-1.10.9
    |         |   └── media
    |         |       ├── css
    |         |       └── js
    |         |
    |         └── Jquery Ui - X.xx.x
    |              ├── js                
    |              └── css
    |                  └── img
    |
    └── routes
        ├── index.hbs
        └── home.hbs
```

Jquery UI is just an example of how it will be with more vendor includes.

If you really have a reason to not put thirdy party js on public folder, you can concat it into your min file "bootbox.min.js".

Into my project all thirdy party plugins are concatenated in my public minified js file with Grunt.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your public dir is your root. You can't access dirs on the same level if public is your root. Move all files you want to access to public. and access them by /dirname/filename when starting with / you start from the root (public)